# Powershell: Delete folder with specific file in it

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I am trying to make a script in powershell to delete all folders in C:\Temp which contains a *.sr_processed file.

I already have this but this only deletes the file and not the folder it was in.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Include *.sr_processed -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one delete files in a folder matching a regular expression using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767489/how-can-one-delete-files-in-a-folder-matching-a-regular-expression-using-powersh)

Comment: @Matthew Sorry but it does not. It also only deletes the file and not the folder which it was located in.

Answer (score 1):

Your are telling it to delete the file. To delete the folder do something like:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Include *.sr_processed -File -Recurse | foreach { Remove-Item –path $_.Directory.Fullname}
```

If you have multiple `.sr_processed` files in a folder it might attempt to delete it more than once. And generally deleting a folder you are globbing is bad practice. So a better idea would be to gather up the folders in a list/hash and delete them at the end.

That would look something like:

```bsh
# declare array
$foldersToDelete = @()
# fill array with folder names
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Include *.sr_processed -File -Recurse | foreach { $foldersToDelete += $_.Directory.Fullname}
# sort and make unique
$foldersToDelete = $foldersToDelete | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
# delete folders
$foldersToDelete | Remove-Item –path $_
```

This is typed from memory, so you might want to adjust it.