# find . -type f -name "*.sw[klmnop]" -delete in Windows?

Tags: vim

Is there an option to delete the swp files in Windows 10, using an equivalent to the command:
`find . -type f -name "*.sw[klmnop]" -delete` in Linux, used for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GUI method**

[Double commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/) has regex file search (ALT-F7), so you can find them by regex like `".*\.sw[klmnop]"`. When you have desired results, press "Feed to listbox" button, it will show all found files on the active panel. Then just select them with CTRL-A and delete permanently with SHIFT-F8.

**CLI method**

Also you can write batch file like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25381530/898116). Sorry, I can't check if it works right now, but it should be like:

```
for /R %%f in (*.sw?) do del /f "%%f"
```

Please NOTE: it will delete all files with 3-letter extension starts with "sw", so be careful. I don't know regex file search on cmd, probably `findstr` could help, it accepts something like regex.

Comment: Here is powershell method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767489/how-can-one-delete-files-in-a-folder-matching-a-regular-expression-using-powersh